# Spacing between MUI Grid items

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

I'm creating a layout of Grids roughly like this:

```
Mon   Tue   Wed   Thu
This is a very very very very very very very very ...                          11.11% achieved
```

I'm nearly there but can not get spacing between the week days (nested inside Typography components). Instead it collapses the space although I specified spacing.

This is my code. How can I control the spacing between the week days?

See codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-playground-vn9p6

```
<Grid container justify="space-between" alignItems="center">
  <Grid item xs={9} container direction="column" spacing={1}>
    <Grid item container spacing={4}>
      <Grid item>
        <Typography variant="caption">Man</Typography>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <Typography variant="caption">Tir</Typography>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <Typography variant="caption">Ons</Typography>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <Typography variant="caption">Tor</Typography>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>

    <Grid item xs>
      <Typography variant="title" noWrap>
        Here is a really really really really really really really really
        really really really really long title
      </Typography>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>

  <Grid item xs={3} container justify="flex-end">
    <Grid item>
      <Typography variant="body">11.11% achieved</Typography>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that this answer is just a debug solution for the auth's demo.

---

Basically add `xs` to child Grid component for your `Grid item` to define the width of each items fit your demand of spacing

```
<Grid item container spacing={12}>
  <Grid item xs={2}>
```

Refer to document and demo [material-ui / grid / spacing](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#spacing)
And related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59389787/material-ui-react-using-grid-spacing-overflows-the-container/59436349#59436349)